# How to write capital "Tau" in MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

The MathJax help says writing `\tau` between `$..$` gives $\tau$  but for capital  "tau", `$\Tau$` does not work. How would one write a capital tau in MathJax?

Comment: Capital Tau in Greek is T. Sure this is useful? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau

Comment: Actually, @Did, what you wrote was a capital Latin "tee". Here is a capital tau: Τ.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Several Greek letters are essentially indistinguishable from Latin letters, and LaTeX (and therefore MathJax) doesn't have separate handling for them for historical reasons, see [this question on Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111544).

What you *can* do is find a "capital tau" somewhere on the internet, such as here: Τ.  Now copy and paste it in between two `$`s, like this `$Τ$`,<sup>*</sup> and note that it renders as

> $Τ$

It's a bit upright, so why not italicise it with `$\it Τ$` to yield

> $\it Τ$

And then look at how it differs from `$T$` (that's a capital Latin tee)

> $T$

Not much of a difference, is there?

<sup>*</sup>  <sub>Alternatively, you can use the `\unicode{}` command, where the argument is the Unicode code point — either decimal or hexidecimal — of the desired character. Capital tau has Unicode code point `932` (decimal) or `x03A4` (hexadecimal), so both `$\unicode{932}$` and `$\unicode{x03A4}$` should produce a captial tau.</sub>

Comment: The fact that they actually bothered to make a capital tau symbol surprises me...

Comment: @AvZ: For the Greek letters? Unicode has those because it makes it possible to automatically convert from capital to lowercase - otherwise, both $\tau$ and $t$ would be possible options when converting $T$ to lowercase and it would be a lot more of a headache than it is now.